# Why my turtle drawing produces different pictures depending on the way I set up amount of pixels?

Tags: python, python-turtle

Can you please explain to me why am I getting different drawings once I set up the amount of pixels specifying the movements?

For example, in the code below I get this picture (In both cases `number_of_angles = 3` and `initial_radius = 100`):

[image]

```
import turtle 
import math

turtle.speed(1)
turtle.shape("turtle")

number_of_angles = int(input("Number of angles? "))
initial_radius = int(input("Initial Radius? "))

sum_angle = 180*(number_of_angles-2)
angle = sum_angle/number_of_angles

Q = 180-(180/number_of_angles)/2
turtle.left(Q) 

for i in range(number_of_angles):
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.left(180-angle)

turtle.done()
```

But when I try to define the number of pixels for a move (instead of `100` I define `initial_size`) I get this picture:

[image]

```
import turtle 
import math

turtle.speed(1)
turtle.shape("turtle")

number_of_angles = int(input("Number of angles? "))
initial_radius = int(input("Initial Radius? "))

sum_angle = 180*(number_of_angles-2)
angle = sum_angle/number_of_angles

Q = 180-(180/number_of_angles)/2
turtle.left(Q) 

initial_size = initial_radius*(2*math.sin(360/(2*number_of_angles)))

for i in range(number_of_angles):
    turtle.forward(initial_size)
    turtle.left(180-angle)

turtle.done()
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your calculation of initial size does not equal 100.

More specifically [math.sin()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#trigonometric-functions) uses radians instead of degrees, resulting in a final value of -60.962124220443336. This causes the turtle to move backwards, resulting in a mirrored and slightly scaled down triangle.

The quickest fix is to convert your angle calculation to radians before passing it to math.sin().

```py
initial_size = initial_radius*(2*math.sin(math.radians(360/(2*number_of_angles))))
```

Answer (score 0):

@sphennings correctly identifies your problem (+1) but I believe there is a *better*, though not *quickest*, fix.  Turtles are happy to work in radians, like the math module, if you ask them to do so:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from math import pi, sin

number_of_angles = int(input("Number of angles? "))
initial_radius = int(input("Initial radius? "))

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.radians()
turtle.shape('turtle')
turtle.speed('slowest')

sum_angle = pi * (number_of_angles - 2)
angle = sum_angle / number_of_angles

Q = pi - (pi / number_of_angles) / 2
turtle.left(Q)

initial_size = 2 * initial_radius * sin(pi / number_of_angles)

for _ in range(number_of_angles):
    turtle.forward(initial_size)
    turtle.left(pi - angle)

screen.exitonclick()
```

Since you only really use 180 degrees in your logic, it's easily replaceable by math.pi